# JavaScript to refresh page every time when someone come to my application tab

Tags: javascript, refresh

Suppose I have opened my application in multiple tabs(e.g. 3 tabs). Now when I change browser tab then I want every time my current tab should show refreshed page. How can we add this behaviour that selecting tab will trigger refresh of page in my application through JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `focus` event on `window`:

```
window.addEventListener("focus", function () {
    console.log("window is focused");
});
```

Comment: When I added location.reload(); then its causing continuous reload in internet explorer. But working fine in chrome.

     window.addEventListener("focus", function() {
      location.reload();
     });

How can we make it reload() to work fine in every browser?

Comment: I was trying like below. this is also not working. Please suggest me.
<script type="text/javascript"> 
           function detectBrowser(){
   var val = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
   if(val.indexOf("chrome") > -1)
   {
  window.addEventListener("focus", function() { 
  location.reload(); 
  });
   } else {
  window.addEventListener("focus", function() {
  if (!localStorage.justOnce) {
   localStorage.setItem("justOnce", "true");
   window.location.reload(true);
  }else{
   localStorage.removeItem("justOnce");
  }
  });
  }
 </script>